# What is the purpose of java.awt.Color.blue and java.awt.Color.BLUE

Tags: java, colors, awt, constants

Why there are two `Color` constants defined in `java.awt.Color` class? For instance

```
public static final Color blue;
public static final Color BLUE;
```

This is obviously redundant. Is there some specific usage scenario - like a best practice where upper case Color is preferred over lower case Color or vice-versa ?

Comment: for myself, I always prefer UPPER_CASE constants

Comment: The lower case constants were created first before the naming conventions were fully ironed out. Then the uppercase ones were created, but the lower case ones remained for backwards compatability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a naming convention thing.

> Java originally defined a few color constant names in lowercase, which
>   violated the naming rule of using uppercase for constants. These are
>   best to use since they are available in all versions of Java:
>   `Color.black`, `Color.darkGray`, `Color.gray`, `Color.lightGray`, `Color.white`,
>   `Color.magenta`, `Color.red`, `Color.pink`, `Color.orange`, `Color.yellow`,
>   `Color.green`, `Color.cyan`, `Color.blue`
>
> Java 1.4 added the proper uppercase names for constants: `Color.BLACK`,
>   `Color.DARK_GRAY`, `Color.GRAY`, `Color.LIGHT_GRAY`, `Color.WHITE`,
>   `Color.MAGENTA`, `Color.RED`, `Color.PINK`, `Color.ORANGE`, `Color.YELLOW`,
>   `Color.GREEN`, `Color.CYAN`, `Color.BLUE`

[Source](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/20color.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Why a comment? It's an answer to the question.

Comment: That page, as are the 1.7 (& presumably earlier) JavaDocs, is slightly incorrect in one aspect.  I am pretty sure it was actually 1.4.1 or (more likely) 1.4.2 that introduced the upper case variants.

Answer (score 3):

They are synonymous. The upper-case names were introduced in Java 1.4 to conform to [Sun's naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) (see Section 9) for constants.